# Vue.js Get the index of a v-for element for an http request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http, v-for

I have an array of posts that have comments for each post, and an input at the bottom of each post to create a new comment. The array has the id of the post attached to its props, but how do I select the specific post I'd create a comment for? I need that specific post id to attach the comment to that post in my database, but I don't know how to select that specific id.

There would be an array of these:

`{"userId": 1, "id": 3, "title": "ea molestias", "body": "et iusto sed quo" }`

```
    <v-row class="mb-6" justify="center">
  <v-col
    xs="12"
    sm="12"
    md="10"
    lg="8"
    v-for="post in posts"
    v-bind:key="post.id"
  >
    <v-card dark>
      <v-card-title class="c-t">Title: {{ post.title }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-subtitle class="text-left c-t"
        >User: {{ post.id }}</v-card-subtitle
      >
      <v-card-text class="text-left"
        >Description: {{ post.description }}</v-card-text
      >

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn text color="warning accent-4">
          Edit
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn text color="red accent-4">
          Delete
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>

      <v-card-text>
        <v-divider class="mx-4"></v-divider>
        <v-card-subtitle class="text-left com-t">Comments</v-card-subtitle>

        <!-- Comments loop -->
        <div class="conditional" v-if="post.comments != null">
          <v-card
            class="mb-2"
            v-for="comment in post.comments"
            v-bind:key="comment.id"
          >
            <v-card-title class="text-left comment"
              >User {{ comment.name }}</v-card-title
            >
            <v-card-subtitle class="text-left comment">{{
              comment.email
            }}</v-card-subtitle>

            <v-card-text class="text-left comment">{{
              comment.body
            }}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </div>
      </v-card-text>

      <!-- Search  -->
      <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation>
        <v-row class="mb-6" justify="center" align="center">
          <v-col xs="6" sm="8" md="8" lg="8">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="comment"
              label="Comment"
              class="ml-2"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col xs="2" sm="2" md="2" lg="2">
            <v-btn color="success" @click="createComment">Send</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Here is my script section:

```
  props: ["posts"],
  data: () => ({
    comment: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    createComment() {
      const newComment = {
        // postId: ,
        name: "Randy Butternubs",
        email: "exampleEmail@someEmail.com",
        body: this.comment,
      };
      this.$emit("create-comment", newComment);
      this.title = "";
    },
  },
```

I'm using `v-model` to grab the comment and create an emit event that will pass it to the parent object to create the post http request. How do I get the current post's id when I click Create comment? That is all I need to finish this create comment request

Here's a link to my github: https://github.com/roninMo/vueRestfulApi/blob/master/src/components/Posts.vue

Comment: Can you paste the relevant parts of your code into your question here on StackOverflow? Links can change or disappear over time, and so pasting your code here ensures the question will be relevant even if the link changes.

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are facing? Grabbing the individual comments within a `v-for` should be a cinch since you've come so far and written such detailed component. If you somehow missed this bit, maybe you should re-read the docs again as there are dozens of example demonstrating templating with arrays.

Comment: I'll check the docs again, but I want to grab the id of the post when I click the createComment button. If I have an array of those posts with comments for each, how do I grab the specific post's id that would be in the props that corresponds to current post I'm creating a comment on

Answer (score 0):

```
                <v-btn color="success" @click="createComment(post.id)">Send</v-btn>
```

You prompt the click function to grab the id then send it with the request. Sorry to waste your time, and thank you for your kindness!